# How to decode this broken emoji string(mojibake) with python or something?

Tags: python, string, encoding, decode, mojibake

Some API that I want to integrate keep giving me '' as 'ğŸ�ƒğŸ�™', and I have no idea to decode it(of course I can't fix that response or know the encoding because the server has no encoding data given).

I've already run `.encode(encoding).decode('utf8')` with all the encodings in Python 3.7 and none of it works. Even tried [ftfy](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy) and other solutions but it doesn't work at all.

Does anyone have any solutions or ideas?

Comment: How do you get the text from API? Is it UTF-8? (this is encoded, so you must decode, I think you invert the transcoding (and possibly you do not need to encode). So your tasks: discover which encoding is the original data, and ev. you should tell us how you read the data (or give us the numeric value, without your encode/decode `[hex(ord(c)) for c in your_string_variable]`

Comment: You can't. The `'ğŸ�ƒğŸ�™'` string is result of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) `''.encode( 'utf-8').decode('cp1254','replace')` where the `'replace'` error handler is a data-loss one…

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I have the values `['0x11f', '0x178', '0xfffd', '0x192', '0x11f', '0x178', '0xfffd', '0x2122']` or `[287, 376, 65533, 402, 287, 376, 65533, 8482]`! Yes, I think is UTF-8 but I don't quite understand why this situation occurred... Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: @JosefZ Oh no lol... Thank you for your kind answer! I think the values are unique to each emoji so I'm thinking of making a table and replace it one by one with regex or something. May I ask how do you think of this idea?

Comment: You gave the value of final string. The problem is before that. Try just not to "encode/decode". You may already have the correct string.

Comment: You can't guess the lost data successfully. For instance, every 3rd character in your string you could replace by one of a lot of byte values. Some could lead to a valid UTF-8 (but some other not) , e.g. `b'\xf0\x9f\x8f\x83\xf0\x9f\x8f\x99\xf0\x9f\x8E\x83\xf0\x9f\x8D\x99'.decode()` returns `''` etc…

Comment: Okay, I'll just check the response again. thx...